# phonegap + Onesignal and minSdkVersion error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, onesignal

I try to run simple app with Onesignal  and I keep getting this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
>
>   > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.3]
>   >     C:\temp\html2\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.onesignal\OneSignal\3.6.3\AndroidManifest.xml
>   >         Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.onesignal" to force usage

This is the code I'm running (Yeah, very simple)

```
 phonegap create html2 --id "li.co.html2" --name "html1.02"
 cd html2
phonegap plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin --save
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova platform add android
cordova platform add ios
phonegap build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reason why you're getting that error is because cordova builds an android project with a [minimum sdk version of 14](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/ad01d28351c13390aff4549258a0f06882df59f5/framework/AndroidManifest.xml), while the library oneSignal requires a minimum version of 15. Rebuild [cordova](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/tree/ad01d28351c13390aff4549258a0f06882df59f5) and set its default [minSdkVersion to 15](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/ad01d28351c13390aff4549258a0f06882df59f5/framework/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" /> in config.xml?

Comment: I should be it, although I was talking about the framework. Look at the links I posted

Comment: as of 2019-12-21 minSdk is 28, i've set the preference to 28, but when i've added onesignal plugin it overrides to 26